# Physics.Raycast not recognising mesh collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, mesh

I am having a problem getting `Physics.Raycast` to recognise a mesh collider. I have a custom created mesh which simulates a terrain, and a camera object which can be controlled with the keyboard and mouse. I am trying to implement collisions between the camera and the terrain, so that the camera cannot move through the terrain.

Here is the script that generates my mesh. It is attached to a GameObject which has a MeshCollider and a MeshFilter component. Pay special attention to where these components have their `mesh` and `sharedMesh` properties set in the script.

```js
var divisions : int;
var size : float;
var height : float;

private var vertices : Vector3[];
private var numVertices : int;

private var cameraStartVertex : Vector3;

function Start () {
    InitTerrain();
}

function InitTerrain() {
    numVertices = (divisions + 1) * (divisions + 1);
    vertices = new Vector3[numVertices];

    var UVs : Vector2[] = new Vector2[numVertices];
    var triangles : int[] = new int[divisions * divisions * 6];

    var halfTerrainSize : float = size / 2;
    var divisionSize : float = size / divisions;

    //LOOK HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    var mesh : Mesh = new Mesh();
    GetComponent.<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
    GetComponent.<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = mesh;
    GetComponent.<MeshCollider>().isTrigger = true;

    var triangleOffset : int = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i <= divisions; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j <= divisions; j++) {
            vertices[i * (divisions+1) + j] = new Vector3(-halfTerrainSize + j * divisionSize, 0.0f, halfTerrainSize - i * divisionSize);
            UVs[i * (divisions+1) + j] = new Vector2(parseFloat(i / divisions), parseFloat(j / divisions));

            if (i < divisions && j < divisions) {
                var topLeft : int = i * (divisions + 1) + j;
                var bottomLeft : int = (i + 1) * (divisions + 1) + j;

                // First triangle of square
                triangles[triangleOffset] = topLeft;
                triangles[triangleOffset + 1] = topLeft + 1;
                triangles[triangleOffset + 2] = bottomLeft + 1;

                // Second triangle of square
                triangles[triangleOffset + 3] = topLeft;
                triangles[triangleOffset + 4] = bottomLeft + 1;
                triangles[triangleOffset + 5] = bottomLeft;

                triangleOffset += 6;
            }
        }
    }

    initDiamondSquareCornerVertices();

    performDiamondSquare();

    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.uv = UVs;
    mesh.triangles = triangles;

    mesh.RecalculateBounds();
    mesh.RecalculateNormals();
}


function initDiamondSquareCornerVertices(){
    vertices[0].y = Random.Range(-height, height);
    vertices[divisions].y = Random.Range(-height, height);
    vertices[vertices.length - 1].y = Random.Range(-height, height);
    vertices[vertices.length - 1 - divisions].y = Random.Range(-height, height);
}

function performDiamondSquare(){
    var numIterations : int = parseInt(Mathf.Log(divisions, 2));
    var numSquares : int = 1;
    var squareSize : int = divisions;

    for (var i = 0; i < numIterations; i++){ // the iteration we're on
        var row : int = 0;

        for (var j = 0; j < numSquares; j++){
            var column : int = 0;

            for (var k = 0; k < numSquares; k++) {
                diamondSquareStep(row, column, squareSize, height);
                column += squareSize;
            }

            row += squareSize;
        }

        numSquares *= 2;
        squareSize /= 2;
        height *= 0.4f;
    }
}

function diamondSquareStep(row : int, column : int, size : int, offset : float) {

    var halfSize : int = parseInt(size * 0.5f);
    var topLeft : int = row * (divisions + 1) + column;
    var bottomLeft : int = (row + size) * (divisions + 1) + column;
    var middle : int = parseInt((row + halfSize) * (divisions + 1) + parseInt(column + halfSize));


    vertices[middle].y = (vertices[topLeft].y + vertices[topLeft + size].y + vertices[bottomLeft].y + vertices[bottomLeft+size].y) / 4 + Random.Range(-offset, offset);


    vertices[topLeft + halfSize].y = (vertices[topLeft].y + vertices[topLeft + size].y + vertices[middle].y) / 3 + Random.Range(-offset, offset);
    vertices[middle - halfSize].y = (vertices[topLeft].y + vertices[bottomLeft].y + vertices[middle].y) / 3 + Random.Range(-offset, offset);
    vertices[middle + halfSize].y = (vertices[topLeft + size].y + vertices[bottomLeft + size].y + vertices[middle].y) / 3 + Random.Range(-offset, offset);
    vertices[bottomLeft + halfSize].y = (vertices[bottomLeft].y + vertices[bottomLeft + size].y + vertices[middle].y) / 3 + Random.Range(-offset, offset);
}
```

And here is the script that is attached to my camera object which controls the camera movement:

```js
#pragma strict

var translationSensitivity : float = 15.0f;

private var mouseX : float;
private var mouseY : float;

function Start () {
    rotX = 0;
    rotZ = 0;
}

function Update () {

    //Translation...
     if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
         var trans : Vector3 = new Vector3(translationSensitivity * Time.deltaTime,0,0);
         if (!checkCollisionImminent(Vector3.right)){
             transform.Translate(trans);
         }
     }
     if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
         trans = new Vector3(-translationSensitivity * Time.deltaTime,0,0);
         if (!checkCollisionImminent(Vector3.left)){
             transform.Translate(trans);
         }
     }
     if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
         trans = new Vector3(0,0,-translationSensitivity * Time.deltaTime);
         if (!checkCollisionImminent(Vector3.back)){
             transform.Translate(trans);
         }
     }
     if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
         trans = new Vector3(0,0,translationSensitivity * Time.deltaTime);
         if (!checkCollisionImminent(Vector3.forward)){
             transform.Translate(trans);
         }
     }
}

function checkCollisionImminent(direction : Vector3) {
    return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, direction, 2);
}
```

You can see I have the collision checking set up. But the camera object continues to move straight through the mesh, and I simply cannot see the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you checked that your distance 2 on raycast is sufficient to get collision with your objects?

Comment: @joreldraw yes, I have tried distance 5 and 10 also, but the camera still moves through the terrain.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you isolate `checkCollisionImminent()` and make it independent of key press. The way it is now, any raycast on a direction other than the direction of movement, will not trigger. I would change the `update()` function accordingly:

```js
function Update () {
    var trans;
    var w, s, a, d;

    //Translation...
     if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
         trans = new Vector3(translationSensitivity * Time.deltaTime,0,0);
     }
     if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
         trans = new Vector3(-translationSensitivity * Time.deltaTime,0,0);
     }
     if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
         trans = new Vector3(0,0,-translationSensitivity * Time.deltaTime);
     }
     if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
         trans = new Vector3(0,0,translationSensitivity * Time.deltaTime);
     }

     //Check collisions
     w = checkCollisionImminent(Vector3.forward);
     s = checkCollisionImminent(Vector3.back);
     a = checkCollisionImminent(Vector3.left);
     d = checkCollisionImminent(Vector3.right);

     //Do nothing if there is a collision
     if(w || s || a || d) {
         return;
     }

     transform.Translate(trans);
}
```

I have not tested this code but it should work fine. Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. The camera continues to move through the terrain.

Comment: Are you able to help any more with this?

Comment: Can't really tell whats wrong... Do you actually see the collider in the Scene view while the program is running? Try setting `GetComponent.<MeshCollider>().convex = true;`. I read from similar posts that usually the generated collider is bigger than the actual mesh so you might have to scale it down. When I was first experimenting with raycasts my ray was hitting the collider of the object that's been cast from. I was using `Physics.Raycast2D()`. If your camera has one, try removing it.

Comment: Other than that I would try to simplify the problem by creating a very basic mesh (something like a flat surface with 4 vertices) with its collider and see if that works.

Comment: How can I make the collider visible in the scene view?

Comment: Okay, I've fixed it. Collisions work, but now my camera gets stuck when it collides with the terrain. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hey, I'm glad you fixed it, what was the problem? Camera gets stuck because in my code I have `if(w||s||a||d) { return; }`. For now its better to forget my code and switch back to your code. But in future if you want to take into account more than one rays at the same time you should add code where the `return` is.